# How to use same options for cmd in the same group by using python-click

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I have code like below, both foo and bar have a **user** option and I need to write:

```
@click.option('--user', default='*')
```

twice for each function.

But I actually have a lot of cmds like this, so it is a lot of repeated code.

```
@click.group(help="cmd group")
def main():
    pass


@click.command(name='foo')
@click.option('--user', default='*')
def foo(user):
    click.secho(user, fg='green')


@click.command(name='bar')
@click.option('--user', default='*')
def bar(user):
    click.secho(user, fg='green')


main.add_command(foo)
main.add_command(bar)
```

What I want is to add the same option to one place in the group of cmd. ow can I do this using click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pass it in the context:

```
@click.group(help="cmd group")
@click.option('--user', default='*')
@click.pass_context
def main(ctx, user):
    ctx.obj = {'user': user}


@click.command(name='foo')
@click.pass_context
def foo(ctx):
    click.secho(ctx.obj['user'], fg='green')


@click.command(name='bar')
@click.pass_context
def bar(ctx):
    click.secho(ctx.obj['user'], fg='green')


main.add_command(foo)
main.add_command(bar)
```

`mycli --user cats bar` will echo cats from the bar subcommand

Answer (score 0):

Method 1. I suppose the name of first parameter of @click.option() is `para`.

```
USER_DEFAULT = {'para' : '--user', 'default' : '*'}

@click.option(**USER_DEFAULT)
```

Method 2. Wrap it in you own decorator filled with default parameters.